# php embedded in html5 not working in aptana

Tags: php, html, embed, aptana3

I'm using aptana to create a mobile web app. Its in html5 and I'm trying to embed some PHP in this in order to make some server calls. To get started I'm just trying to make a simple echo statement in my html5. What is wrong with this embedded echo statement so that it is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" class="type-home">
        <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>JQM : Customize ListView</h1> 
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php echo 'While this is going to be parsed.'; ?>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
        <li><a href="#"> <h1>Country Name : Thailand </h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <h1>Country Name : China </h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <h1>Country Name : Malaysia </h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <h1>Country Name : India </h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <h1>Country Name : Indonesia </h1></a></li>
        </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how did you saved this file as `.html` OR `.php`? It should be `.php`.

Comment: I made the file .php and now it just terminates when debugging. aptana does have the correct path to my php.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Php statements work at server side. So if your server has php and running it, it can be processed.

To make a file processed by php, during it is being output from server, it has to have a file extension as

```
afile.php
```

not

```
afile.html
```

so the server will invoke php and php will run commands which are relevant for it.

Comment: I changed the .html etension to .php and now it terminates when debugging. Aptana does have the correct path to my php.exe file.

Comment: And what does this have to do with the answer? Aptana is an ide, if you are to use it, you have to learn it. Google it, read the documentation and fix it.